# Looping through relationship stored from an array in laravel

Tags: laravel, relationship

Is it possible to loop through an array which stores the relationships name like this?

```
$input_list1 = ['certificateQualification()','surgeryExperience()','assocOrganization()','mediaWebsite()'];   

    foreach ($input_list1 as $key => $value) {
      // dd($user->$value);  //null
      // dd($user->certificateQualification);
      // dd($user->certificateQualification()->isEmpty());  //false
    }
```

*dd($user->$value);* returns null now

$user->certificateQualification()

```
App\Models\UserCustomData {#4603
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "user_custom_data"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:6 [
    "id" => 229
    "user_id" => 3
    "type_id" => 1
    "content" => "test1"
    "created_at" => "2020-04-30 15:18:28"
    "updated_at" => "2020-04-30 15:18:28"
  ]
  #original: array:6 [
    "id" => 229
    "user_id" => 3
    "type_id" => 1
    "content" => "test1"
    "created_at" => "2020-04-30 15:18:28"
    "updated_at" => "2020-04-30 15:18:28"
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

I'm able to loop through database variables like this

```
    $profile_completion = 0;
    $input_list = [];
    $input_list[0] = ['veterinarian_type','area_of_skill'];
    $input_list[1] = ['id','role_id','first_name','first_kana_name','nick_name','email','phone_number','gender','dob'];
    $input_list[2] = ['self_description'];   


   $complete_list = [];
    foreach ($input_list as $key => $value) {
      $flag = 1;
      foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
        if (!$user->$value1) {
          $flag = 0;
        }
      }
      if ($flag == 1) {
        $complete_list[$key] = 10;
      }else{
        $complete_list[$key] = 0;
      }
    }
```

I would like to avoid these steps (i'm currently using this )

```
    if ($user->certificateQualification()->isEmpty()) {
      $complete_list[3] = 10;
    }else{
      $complete_list[3] = 0;
    }

    if ($user->surgeryExperience()->isEmpty()) {
      $complete_list[4] = 10;
    }else{
      $complete_list[4] = 0;
    }
    dd($complete_list);

    if ($user->assocOrganization()->isEmpty()) {
      $complete_list[5] = 10;
    }else{
      $complete_list[5] = 0;
    }

    if ($user->mediaWebsite()->isEmpty()) {
      $complete_list[6] = 10;
    }else{
      $complete_list[6] = 0;
    }
```

This is my user model

```
public function customData()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserCustomData', 'user_id','id');
}

public function certificateQualification()
{
    return $this->customData->where('type_id',1);
}

public function surgeryExperience()
{
    return $this->customData->where('type_id',2);
}
```

Can i really loop over the relationship? Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: is `certificateQualification()` a relationship method?

Comment: i've updated the question, and added relationship on user model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the method by string with `()` like this:

```php
$input_list1 = ['certificateQualification','surgeryExperience','assocOrganization','mediaWebsite'];   
foreach ($input_list1 as $key => $value) {
    dd($user->$value()); // $user will call the method certificateQualification()
}
```

#### For better performance:

And in those method, you are calling all the relationship datas of user, and filter all those datas by collection method `where('type_id', 1)`, you can optimize it like this:

```php
public function certificateQualification()
{
    // this one will return the eloquent builder of customData,
    // if you want to get the datas, try $user->certificateQualification()->get()
    return $this->customData()->where('type_id', 1); 
}
```

And check this query is empty by `exists()` method:

```php
foreach ($input_list1 as $key => $value) {
    if ($user->$value()->exists()) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: it worked, but the exists() function showing this error:-  Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::exists does not exist.

Comment: @Nadiya yes, if you want to use `exists` , you need to change the method to `$this->customData()->where('type_id', 1); `; check the `customData()` has bracket, it will return eloquent builder instead of collection.

Comment: @Nadiya Calling `->customData` without bracket will equals to `->customData()->get()`, it will return the datas out of database, and return collection. Here I recommend to call `customData` with bracket, so the datas still in database, use `where()` before `->get()` will filter datas in database, and takes less datas out of db. this one has better performance.